# Data filter for export to excel

Tags: django, filter, openpyxl

I added a save button to the Excel file from the database. now we need this button to use all the filters applied in the dashboard in the table tag, here is the html code

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">

        <thead class="table-light">
                <tr>
    
                    <th scope="col"> ID </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Адресс размещения </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Тип </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Категория </th>
                    <th scope="col"> № Инвентаря </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Дата эксплуатации </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Наименование инвентаря </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Состояние </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Редактировать </th>
    
                </tr>
    
        </thead>
    
        <tbody>
               
            {% if page_obj %}
    
                {% for record in page_obj %}
    
                <tr>
    
                    <td> {{record.id}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.depart}} </td>
    
                    <td>{{record.types}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.category}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.invent_number}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.day}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.name}} </td>
    
                    <td> {{record.state}} </td>
    
                    <td> 
                   
                                                   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recordModal{{ record.id }}">Редакт</button>
  
                                                            <!-- Modal -->
                              <div class="modal fade" id="recordModal{{ record.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="recordModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="recordModalLabel">Информация о записи</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p><strong>Департамент:</strong> {{record.depart}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>№ кабинета:</strong> {{record.number}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Категория:</strong> {{record.category}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Тип:</strong> {{record.types}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Ответственный:</strong> {{record.otvet}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>№ Инвентаря:</strong> {{record.invent_number}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Дата эксплуатации:</strong> {{record.day}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Наименование инвентаря:</strong> {{record.name}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Начальная цена:</strong> {{record.price}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Коментарии:</strong> {{record.info}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Пользователь:</strong> {{record.cr_user}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Дата создания:</strong> {{record.date}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                                            <a href="{% url 'update-record' record.id %}" class="btn btn-info">Редактировать запись</a>
                                            <a href="{% url 'delete-record' record.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"> Удалить &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% empty %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">Нет записей</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

views.py

```
# - Dashboard
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def dashboard(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('my-login')
    my_user = User_amon.objects.filter(login=request.user)
    if request.user.username == 'admin':
        my_records = Invent.objects.all()
    else:
        my_records = Invent.objects.filter(cr_user=my_user[0].login.id).order_by("-date")

    myFilter = InventFilter(request.GET, queryset=my_records)
    my_records = myFilter.qs

    paginator = Paginator(my_records, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
        'records': my_records,
        'myFilter': myFilter,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'tik/dashboard.html', context=context)
```

I also created an excel.py file here is the code from it to save the excel file

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from django.http import HttpResponse
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Alignment, Border, Side, Font
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import *
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
 


# EXCEL
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def export_invent_to_excel(request):
    # Получаем все объекты модели Invent
    invent_data = Invent.objects.all().order_by('id')

    # Создаем новый файл Excel
    workbook = Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    # Добавляем заголовки столбцов и применяем стилизацию
    sheet['A1'] = 'Р/Т'
    sheet['B1'] = 'Сурогаи чойгиршави'
    sheet['C1'] = '№ кабинет'
    sheet['D1'] = 'Категория'
    sheet['E1'] = 'Тип'
    sheet['F1'] = 'Ному насаби шахси вобаста'
    sheet['G1'] = '№ инаентари'
    sheet['H1'] = 'Санаи ба истифодадихи'
    sheet['I1'] = 'Номгуи воситаи асоси'
    sheet['J1'] = 'Арзиш дар аввал'
    sheet['K1'] = 'Состояние'
    sheet['L1'] = 'Эзох'
    sheet['A2'] = '1'
    sheet['B2'] = '2'
    sheet['C2'] = '3'
    sheet['D2'] = '4'
    sheet['E2'] = '5'
    sheet['F2'] = '6'
    sheet['G2'] = '7'
    sheet['H2'] = '8'
    sheet['I2'] = '9'
    sheet['J2'] = '10'
    sheet['K2'] = '11'
    sheet['L2'] = '12'
    
    header_font = Font(bold=True)  # Создаем объект шрифта для заголовков
    for cell in sheet[1]:  # Применяем стилизацию для заголовков в первой строке
        cell.font = header_font

    # Применить стили к первым двум строкам
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=2):
        for cell in row:
            cell.font = Font(color='0000FF', bold=True)  # Синий цвет и полужирный шрифт
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

    # Автоматически подстроить размеры столбцов
    for column in sheet.columns:
        max_length = 0
        column_letter = column[0].column_letter

        for cell in column:
            try:
                if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                    max_length = len(str(cell.value))
            except TypeError:
                pass

        adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2  # Дополнительное пространство для улучшения читаемости текста
        sheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = adjusted_width

    # Определить стиль границы
    border_style = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),
                        right=Side(style='thin'),
                        top=Side(style='thin'),
                        bottom=Side(style='thin'))

    # Пройтись по каждой строке и нарисовать границы
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        has_value = False  # Флаг, указывающий, есть ли запись в строке

        for cell in row:
            if cell.value:
                has_value = True
                break

        if has_value:
            for cell in row:
                cell.border = border_style

    # Заполняем данными
    for index, invent in enumerate(invent_data, start=3):
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=1, value=index-2)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=2, value=invent.depart.name if invent.depart else None)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=3, value=invent.number)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=4, value=invent.category.name)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=5, value=invent.types.name)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=6, value=invent.otvet)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=7, value=invent.invent_number)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=8, value=invent.day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if invent.day else None)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=9, value=invent.name)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=10, value=invent.price)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=11, value=invent.state.name)
        sheet.cell(row=index, column=12, value=invent.info)

    # Применить стиль границы к текущей строке
        for cell in sheet[index]:
            cell.border = border_style

    # Применить стиль границы к последней строке
    last_row_index = len(invent_data) + 2  # +2 для учета заголовков строк
    for cell in sheet[last_row_index]:
        cell.border = border_style

    # Создаем HTTP-ответ с файлом Excel
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=invent_data.xlsx'
    workbook.save(response)

    return response
```

when you click on the button, all data from the database is saved in excel, I need to filter it so that each user receives exactly the data that he entered or filtered

filter.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Invent
from django.db.models import Q

class InventFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='my_custom_filter',label="Search")  
    class Meta:
        model = Invent
        fields = ['q','depart','category','types','invent_number','date','state','name'] #'all'
    def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(depart__name__icontains=value) |
                               Q(category__name__icontains=value) |
                               Q(types__name__icontains=value) |
                               Q(name__icontains=value) |
                               Q(state__name__icontains=value) |
                               Q(invent_number__icontains=value) )
```